# Picking one of each color

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $a$ balls of color A, $b$ balls of color B, $c$ balls of color C in the bag and $d$ balls of color D in a bag. What are the chances that when I take four balls out of the bag at the same time, I take out one of each color?

So I realised that there were $^{a+b+c+d}C_{4}$ ways of picking them. I also realised that there were $4!$ permutations of picking. How go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinations is the most natural approach.

- Choose $1$ ball from $A$:$\;{\large{\binom{a}{1}}}$ choices.

  Choose $1$ ball from $B$:$\;{\large{\binom{b}{1}}}$ choices.

  Choose $1$ ball from $C$:$\;{\large{\binom{c}{1}}}$ choices.

  Choose $1$ ball from $D$:$\;{\large{\binom{d}{1}}}$ choices.

By the multiplication rule, there are
$$
{\small{\binom{a}{1}}}
{\small{\binom{b}{1}}}
{\small{\binom{c}{1}}}
{\small{\binom{d}{1}}}
=abcd
$$
sets of $4$ balls, with one from each of $A,B,C,D$.

Since the number of possible sets of $4$ balls is 
$${\small{\binom{a+b+c+d}{4}}}$$
it follows that the required probability is
$$
\frac
{
abcd
}
{
{\large{\binom{a+b+c+d}{4}}}
}
$$
Notice that this approach would work just as well if you were asked, for example, to find the probability of selecting $10$ balls with

- $1$ ball from $A$

  $2$ balls from $B$

  $3$ balls from $C$

  $4$ balls from $D$

assuming $a+b+c+d\ge 10$.

Following the same approach, the required probability would be
$$
\frac
{
\binom{a}{1}\binom{b}{2}\binom{c}{3}\binom{d}{4}
}
{
{\large{\binom{a+b+c+d}{10}}}
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

So you are going to put $^{a+b+c+d}C_{4}=\binom{a+b+c+d}{4}$ at the denominator. Then, as regards the numerator of the fraction which gives the probability, consider the product $abcd$: we have $a$ ways to pick a ball of color A, $b$ ways to pick a ball ball of color B...

Answer (score 0):

Ive got it!! There are 24 permutations possible. Each permutation has the probability of $\frac{abcd}{^{a+b+c+d}C_4}$ Multiply this by 24, and dada!

Please check this; I am not so sure.

Comment: That is $\frac{abcd}{^{a+b+c+d}C_{4}}$. See my hint.

Comment: @RobertZ good point

Comment: The probability is $\frac{abcd}{^{a+b+c+d}C_4}$ no need to multiply by $24$. See the case when $a=b=c=d=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we extract

- ball A $p=\frac{a}(n)$
- ball B $p=\frac{b}(n-1)$
- ball C $p=\frac{c}(n-2)$
- ball D $p=\frac{d}(n-3)$

and we have 4! different ways.